# How to add normal modules to Nuxt 3

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js, stomp, nuxtjs3, sockjs

I am writing a web application in Nuxt 3 and want to integrate a `SockJs over Stomp` websocket. Now I have written the component...

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Test</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import {useRouter, ref} from "#imports";
import SockJS from "sockjs-client";
import {Stomp} from "@stomp/stompjs";

let consoleText = ref<string>("");

interface ConsoleMessage {
  messageContent: string,
  user: string,
}

const props = defineProps<{
  originURL:string,
  publicURL:string,
  privateURL:string
}>();

let stompClient: any = null;
function connect() {
  const socket = new SockJS(props.originURL);
  stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
  stompClient.connect({}, function () {
    stompClient.subscribe(props.publicURL, function (message: { body: string; }) {
      showMessage(JSON.parse(message.body));
    });
    stompClient.subscribe(props.privateURL, function (message: { body: string; }) {
      showMessage(JSON.parse(message.body));
    });
  });
}

function showMessage(message: ConsoleMessage) {
  consoleText.value = "\n" + message.messageContent + "\n";
}

connect();
</script>
```

I have imported `@stomp/stompjs` and `sockjs-client` via `yarn add`. What do I have to change in the `nuxt.config.ts` to make it so that the application loads the modules.

Edit:

Following the advice given by `nur_iyad` I attempted to write a plugin

```
import {defineNuxtPlugin} from "nuxt/app";
import SockJS from "sockjs-client";
import {CompatClient, Stomp} from "@stomp/stompjs";
import {Message} from "~/composables/display";

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
    nuxtApp.provide('sock', () => new NuxtSockJs())
})

declare module '#app' {
    interface NuxtApp {
        $sock (): NuxtSockJs
    }
}

export class NuxtSockJs {
    stompInstance: CompatClient | null;

    constructor() {
        this.stompInstance = null;
    }

    connect(originURL:string,
            subscribeURLs:Array<string>,
            displayMessage: (message: Message) => any): void {
        const socket = new SockJS(originURL);
        let stompClient: CompatClient = Stomp.over(socket);
        stompClient.connect({}, function () {
            for(const subscribeURL of subscribeURLs) {
                stompClient.subscribe(subscribeURL, function (message: { body: string; }) {
                    displayMessage(JSON.parse(message.body));
                });
            }
        });
        this.stompInstance = stompClient;
    }
    sendMessage(sendURL: string, message: Message):void {
        (this.stompInstance)!.send(sendURL, {}, JSON.stringify(message));
    }
}
```

This does not work and just throws the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined
    at node_modules/sockjs-client/lib/utils/browser-crypto.js
```

Comment: I think you can use plugins. Nuxt automatically reads the files in your plugins directory and loads them at the creation of the Vue application. You can use .server or .client suffix in the file name to load a plugin only on the server or client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long hunt for an answer I have found the solution.

It is literally just importing the module into any TS activated component, in my case I packaged the SockJS into a composable

```
import {CompatClient, Stomp} from "@stomp/stompjs";
import {Message} from "~/composables/display";
import SockJS from "sockjs-client";

export class NuxtSockJs {
    stompInstance: CompatClient | null;
    isConnected: boolean;

    constructor() {
        this.stompInstance = null;
        this.isConnected = false;
    }

    connect(originURL:string,
            subscribeURLs:Array<string>,
            displayMessage: (message: Message) => any): void {
        const socket = new SockJS(originURL);
        this.stompInstance = Stomp.over(socket);
        this.stompInstance.debug = () => {};
        this.stompInstance.connect({}, () => {
            for(const subscribeURL of subscribeURLs) {
                this.stompInstance!.subscribe(subscribeURL, (message) => {
                    displayMessage(JSON.parse(message.body));
                });
            }
        });
        this.isConnected = true;
    }
    sendMessage(sendURL: string, message: Message):void {
        (this.stompInstance)!.send(sendURL, {}, JSON.stringify(message));
    }
}
```

For anybody interested as to why SockJS would still not work, the following has to be added to the `nuxt.config.ts`

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    app: {
        head: {
            script: [
                {children: 'var global = window;'}
            ]
        }
    }
});
```

Hope this helps anybody suffering from the issues I was :))